# ColdFusion Google Adwords Business Component Error

Tags: coldfusion, google-ads-api

I am using Martin Orth's ColdFusion API for Google Adwords. I have been able to fix some errors to get the API working in most cases, but am running into a roadblock when I try to use the business.cfc component. I try to create the component the same way I have successfully created them for other components of the API with the syntax:

cfset oBusiness=createObject("component","com.google.adwords.api.v12.business")>

The results in a:

coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.google.adwords.api.v12.business][coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$NoSuchTemplateException : Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface long.]

even though the business.cfc file is located as the specified path and has not been modified. Has anyone been able to get this component to work? If so, can you post a copy of your business.cfc file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the CFC mapping in CF Administration

Comment: fyi cold fusion and ColdFusion are two very different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rewrote the entire code minus comments and hints (in past files there were many illegal chars) in a new file and it worked fine.

Comment: Hey Jeff- Are you using the CF Adwords Client Library? I'm trying to usine Martin Orth's solution and can get most of it working, but could use some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version (V201101) of the AdWords API library for ColdFusion at http://www.cfsolutions.de/coldfusion_adwords_api/docs/index.cfm